# conda build tarball error when using pkg_format 2

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-build

When using conda-build, consistently getting tarball error when setting `conda config --set conda_build.pkg_format 2`. The `meta.yaml` file is below. Project compiles when when using default `pkg_format`, but fails for `.conda` format. Clearing caches does not fix the issue, so unclear what problem is.

Running command `conda-build --python=3.9 --output-folder conda-bld conda`

```yaml
package:
  name: foo
  version: 0.0.4

source:
    path: ../

build:
    number: 0
    noarch: python
    script: {{ PYTHON }} -m pip install .

requirements:
  build:
    - numpy

  host:
    - python
    - setuptools
    - pip

  run:
    - python >=3.7
    - numpy >=1.24.0
```

Error is:

```py
Packaging foo
INFO:conda_build.build:Packaging foo
Packaging foo-0.0.4-py_0
INFO:conda_build.build:Packaging foo-0.0.4-py_0
number of files: 9
Fixing permissions
::CHECKING MATCHES::
::CHECKING MATCHES::
INFO :: Time taken to mark (prefix)
        0 replacements in 0 files was 0.25 seconds
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\image_tools\Scripts\conda-build-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\image_tools\lib\site-packages\conda_build\cli\main_build.py", line 593, in main
    execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\image_tools\lib\site-packages\conda_build\cli\main_build.py", line 573, in execute
    outputs = api.build(
  File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\image_tools\lib\site-packages\conda_build\api.py", line 253, in build
    return build_tree(
  File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\image_tools\lib\site-packages\conda_build\build.py", line 3799, in build_tree
    packages_from_this = build(
  File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\image_tools\lib\site-packages\conda_build\build.py", line 2875, in build
    newly_built_packages = bundlers[pkg_type](output_d, m, env, stats)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\image_tools\lib\site-packages\conda_build\build.py", line 2071, in bundle_conda
    verifier.verify_package(
  File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\image_tools\lib\site-packages\conda_verify\verify.py", line 20, in verify_package
    package_check = CondaPackageCheck(path_to_package)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\image_tools\lib\site-packages\conda_verify\checks.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.archive = tarfile.open(self.path)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\image_tools\lib\tarfile.py", line 1625, in open
    raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

Here is the output of conda list on the environment

```
anaconda-client           1.12.0           py39haa95532_0
attrs                     23.1.0             pyh71513ae_1    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.12.2             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
boltons                   23.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
brotli-python             1.0.9            py39h99910a6_9    conda-forge
build                     0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
bzip2                     1.0.8                h8ffe710_4    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2023.7.22            h56e8100_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2023.7.22          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.15.1           py39h68f70e3_3    conda-forge
chardet                   5.1.0            py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        3.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.1.6           win_pyh7428d3b_0    conda-forge
clyent                    1.2.2                      py_1    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
conda                     23.5.2           py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
conda-build               3.25.0           py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
conda-index               0.2.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
conda-package-handling    2.0.2              pyh38be061_0    conda-forge
conda-package-streaming   0.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
conda-verify              3.1.1           py39hcbf5309_1006    conda-forge
cryptography              41.0.2           py39hb6bd5e6_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
filelock                  3.12.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
future                    0.18.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
glob2                     0.7                        py_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib_resources       6.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2023.2.0         h57928b3_49496    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
jpeg                      9e                   hcfcfb64_3    conda-forge
jsonpatch                 1.32               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonpointer               2.0                        py_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                4.18.4             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonschema-specifications 2023.7.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.3.1            py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
libarchive                3.6.2                h6f8411a_1    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0              17_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0              17_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.14                 hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h8ffe710_5    conda-forge
libhwloc                  2.9.1           nocuda_h15da153_6    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0              17_win64_mkl    conda-forge
liblief                   0.12.3               h63175ca_0    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.39               h19919ed_0    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.42.0               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.4.0                hc4f729c_5    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.11.4               hc3477c8_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hcfcfb64_5    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.4                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
lzo                       2.10              he774522_1000    conda-forge
m2-msys2-runtime          2.5.0.17080.65c939c               3    conda-forge
m2-patch                  2.7.5                         2    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2    conda-forge
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.3            py39ha55989b_0    conda-forge
menuinst                  1.4.19           py39hcbf5309_1    conda-forge
mkl                       2022.1.0           h6a75c08_874    conda-forge
more-itertools            10.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.9.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.25.1           py39h816b6a6_0    conda-forge
openssl                   3.1.1                hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
packaging                 23.1               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pip                       23.2.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pkginfo                   1.9.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
platformdirs              3.9.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pluggy                    1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.5            py39ha55989b_0    conda-forge
pthreads-win32            2.9.1                hfa6e2cd_3    conda-forge
py-lief                   0.12.3           py39h99910a6_0    conda-forge
pycosat                   0.6.4            py39ha55989b_1    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 23.2.0             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
pyproject-hooks           1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.7.1              pyh0701188_6    conda-forge
python                    3.9.16          h4de0772_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-fastjsonschema     2.18.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-libarchive-c       5.0              py39hcbf5309_1    conda-forge
python_abi                3.9                      3_cp39    conda-forge
pytz                      2023.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pywin32                   304              py39h99910a6_2    conda-forge
pyyaml                    6.0              py39ha55989b_5    conda-forge
referencing               0.30.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.31.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
requests-toolbelt         1.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ripgrep                   13.0.0               h7f3b576_2    conda-forge
rpds-py                   0.9.2            py39hf21820d_0    conda-forge
ruamel.yaml               0.17.32          py39ha55989b_0    conda-forge
ruamel.yaml.clib          0.2.7            py39ha55989b_1    conda-forge
setuptools                68.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
simpleitk                 2.2.0            py39h82bb817_0    simpleitk
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
soupsieve                 2.3.2.post1        pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sphinx                    5.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tbb                       2021.9.0             h91493d7_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
tomli                     2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
toolz                     0.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.65.0             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.7.1                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.7.1              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2023c                h71feb2d_0    conda-forge
ucrt                      10.0.22621.0         h57928b3_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   2.0.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.3                h64f974e_17    conda-forge
vc14_runtime              14.36.32532         hfdfe4a8_17    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.36.32532         h05e6639_17    conda-forge
wheel                     0.41.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
win_inet_pton             1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_6    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h8d14728_0    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                h8ffe710_2    conda-forge
zipp                      3.16.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.13               hcfcfb64_5    conda-forge
zstandard                 0.19.0           py39h95af829_2    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.2                h12be248_7    conda-forge
```

Comment: Hmm. Not sure if it's related: https://github.com/conda/conda-verify/issues/88 Unfortunately, just some ["*what did you see?!*" vibes](https://xkcd.com/979/). The `tarfile.py` being directly in `lib/` is kinda weird; it's always under `lib/python3.x/` for me. Can you the provenance of that file? (`conda package -w`)

Comment: Want me to run that on the outputted file that is failing on the `tarfile.py`? The issue seems that the `tarfile.py` is trying to read the `.conda` file, but it is unsuccessful. It does seem similar to that issue, but never resolved...

Comment: I'm suggesting to run: `conda package -w D:\Miniconda3\envs\image_tools\lib\tarfile.py` to find out where that file is from. Possibly could just be a Windows thing (on Unix the `tarfile.py` is located in a different directory). Also, it is not recommended to have `conda` and `conda-build` installed in a non-**base** environment. It can lead to undefined behavior, though that doesn't mean that's the issue here.

Comment: Here is the output 
`conda package -w tarfile.py -> tarfile.py  conda-forge/win-64::python-3.9.16-h4de0772_0_cpython`